# How to disable contact section ( message , call , video , mail ) from CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I want to know it possible to remove or disable menu in that section.

Thank you.

```
extension ViewController: CNContactPickerDelegate {
@IBAction func pickerBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let contacVC = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contacVC.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPostalAddressesKey]
    contacVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

    contacVC.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey, CNContactIdentifierKey];
    contacVC.delegate = self
    self.present(contacVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
    if let phone = contactProperty.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
        print(phone.stringValue)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
let cncontactVC = CNContactViewController()
cncontactVC.allowsActions = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use instance property **allowsActions** of CNContactViewController.

From the official docs,

> Determines whether to display buttons for actions such as sending a
>   text message or initiating a FaceTime call.

while creating an object of CNContactViewController,

```
let contactVC = CNContactViewController()
contactVC.allowsActions = false
```

There are other useful properties as well ,

- **shouldShowLinkedContacts**
- **allowsEditing**